# Prioritize a peer?

Tags: bittorrent, bandwidth, utorrent

I'm a Utorrent user, and am currently seeding a rather large file set.  I have allocated a seedbox that I want to use to share the torrent with much higher bandwidth than I currently have.  However, it's not a popular download, and I don't expect a ton of people to get it, so peers are few, but my seed box is downloading from me.  My question is, it there a way to give priority to the seedbox downloading from me?  Can I give all my upload bandwidth to that one IP instead of spreading it out over the swarm?  I want to upload only to the seedbox.  Since I already have uploaded the torrent and started seeding it before I got the box, most of the people have most of the file set.  So the seedbox caught up rather quickly.  Now, it is with the rest of them, just waiting on my slow Internet speed.  If I could dedicate to one IP, it would complete much faster.

Anyone know of a way to make this happen, or a client that will?

Comment: As you are a seed, why couldn't you use something like a firewall and block connections to all other clients except your seedbox?

Comment: If I wanted to go that far I would just kill the torrent, upload via FTP, and start over, but I am already about 70% in.  I don't want to start over.  Using the firewall would also kill any other torrents I might be peering/seeding.  I'm pretty sure it's not possible without editing the registry, but I thought I would ask in case someone out there had figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by creating a `ipfilter.dat` file in the same directory that uTorrent stores the `settings.dat` file. (Usually: `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`)

If, for example, the seedbox has the IP: `123.45.67.89`
then the `ipfilter.dat` file should be:

```
0.0.0.0 - 123.45.67.88
123.45.67.90 - 255.255.255.255
```

to block all peers except the seedbox.

Answer (score 0):

**Tixati** (torrent client) have this feature. You have just to do a right click over that peer, then go to **Bandwidth** > **Priority Group**, and give him higher/lower priority.

Answer (score -1):

```
Torrent.properties.initial-seeding = true
```

[Initial seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-seeding) seeds only the pieces that haven't been seeded yet. Other peers who have a piece that the seedbox doesn't will send.

Comment: So, what should OP do with that?

Comment: Edit the full info of your comments into the answer. Don't just leave a one liner.

Answer (score -1):

You could make your `upload slot = 1` this will make sure all your bandwith gets consumed by a single peer, however if your peer disconnects yor Bittorrent client will try to make another connection....
I don't know since my Windows days are long ago over, but `Azureus` had something called as Super Seed feature which had many customizations available so you could increase your `Timeout` so that if the peer seeding to disconnects your Bittorent client will wait sometime before it disconnects with it.....
Hope this helps.......